# Proving that a set is not compact directly from the definition

Tags: complex-analysis, compactness

Prove that the disk $D(a;R)=\{z:\lvert z-a \rvert<R \} $ is not compact.

I know that we can prove that the set is not closed or not bounded and we can deduce directly that the set is not compact by the Heine-Borel Theorem, but I want to prove it directly from the definition.

Comment: Present an open cover with no finite subcover. A different example: the set $(0,1)$ has the cover $\{ (1/n,1-1/n) : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, but this cover has no finite subcover, because the union of any finite subcover is $(1/N,1-1/N)$ for some $N$, which does not contain all of $(0,1)$. Your example is actually very similar to this one.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the metric space $(\mathbb{C}, \rho)$ whose matric is given by 
$$\rho: \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}, \text{ with } \rho(z_1,z_2) = |z_1-z_2|.$$
Then is an open ball of radius $R$ centered at $a$, that is,
$$D(a;R) := \{z \in \mathbb{C} : \rho(z,a) < R\}.$$ 
Now, a set is compact is every open cover has a finite subcover. For $n>1$, consider the set, 
$$\mathcal{O}_n := D(a; R-\frac{1}{n}).$$
Clearly, the collection $\{\mathcal{O}_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ covers $D(a;R)$. Notice that for $z \in D(a; R)$ and sufficiently large $n$, $z \in D(a; R-\frac{1}{n})$ and as $n$ approach infinity, it does cover $D(a;R)$. But any finite subcover, say
$\{\mathcal{O}_{n_j}\}_{j=1}^m,$
will cover only $D(a; R-\frac{1}{N})$, where
$$N = \max \{n_j\}.$$
This proves that $D(a;R)$ is not compact.

Comment: Why are you writing intervals?

Comment: To be more specific, I'm pretty sure that what you want is actually $D(a,R-1/n)$.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to say exactly what you wrote, thanks.